# Где размещать css и js файлы - в начале или конце документа?

Tags: html, производительность

Как, всё-таки, правильно подключать стили и js файлы?

Во многих источниках указано, что наиболее верным является такой способ:
css в начале(в head), а js в конце, перед закрытием . Но когда я смотрю на крупнейших ресурсах как это сделано, то получается везде по-разному, а ведь, как я понимаю, крупнейшие ресурсы заботятся о скорости загрузки сайта в первую очередь. Кто-то всё размещает в head, кто-то и так, и сяк.

Или тут есть какие-то "подводные камни" на которые стоит обратить внимание? Просто весьма интересно. Сам всегда размещаю css в начале, а все js в конце.

Comment: Крупнейшие ресурсы проверяли на скорость? Действительно все быстрые? Просто интересно, не подумайте ничего. Парочку как-то проверяла, а там о скорости и речи нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Почему модель css вверху, js внизу более привлекательная?**

Тут важный момент это то, что **браузер загружает страницу сверху вниз**

**Сценарий №1**

Есть страница на которой скрипты и стили вверху

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- here is page content -->             
    </body>
</html>
```

Примерный сценарий ее загрузки будет такой:

1. Загрузка стилей
2. Загрузка скриптов
3. Загрузка остальной разметки

В данном сценарии есть недостаток, до момента отображения непосредственно контента страницы браузер должен загрузить стили и скрипты, что дает довольно большую задержку если это крупный ресурс.

**Сценарий №2**

Есть страница на которой стили вверху, а скрипты перед закрывающим тегом body

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">       
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- here is page content -->             
        <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Примерный сценарий ее загрузки будет такой:

1. Загрузка стилей
2. Загрузка разметки
3. Загрузка скриптов

В данном сценарии есть преимущества по сравнению с первым, до момента отображения непосредственно контента страницы браузер должен загрузить только стили, а скрипты он загрузит в последнюю очередь, что позволяет пользователю быстрее увидеть содержимое страницы.

**Почему стили стоит оставлять вверху?**
Если стили также как и скрипты перенести вниз страницы то разметка после загрузки будет не стилизована, что будет выглядеть довольно некрасиво до момента загрузки стилей.

Comment: В первом случае "браузер должен загрузить стили и скрипты". Скрипты загружаются асинхронно, как правило, поэтому не аргумент.

Comment: @edem, полагаю Вы не совсем правы, до момента загрузки всех скриптов идет блокировка дальнейшего рендера страницы. Т.е если в хедере есть скрипты то разметка не будет генерироваться до тех пор пока все скрипты в хедере не будут загружены и обработаны. Приведите аргументы если я не прав.

Comment: Нет, в Вашем примере у Вас правильные выводы, это я забыл что для изменения поведения необходимо явно указывать параметры загрузки скриптов с помощью defer или async. Подробнее https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-async

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите в конец то, что не является необходимым для оформления вашего сайта. Ведь при открытии сайта пользователь вначале видит его, а потом - взаимодействует с ним. Если (условно говоря) в каком-то скрипте у вас стоит изменение шрифтов (в зависимости от устройства, размера экрана, Math.random() =)), то этот скрипт имеет смысл разместить повыше, что бы пользователь скорее увидел сайт в нужном виде. Если же какой-то скрипт занимаются обработкой изображений предпросмотров, подгрузку статей по мере прокрутки или выполняет ещё какие-то действия, не влияющие на то, что видит пользователь в первое мгновение открытия сайта - вынесите это ниже.

В общем, перефразируя один лозунг, - "функционал ничто, вид - всё!" :)