# CSS не успевает за загрузкой

Tags: css

Всем добрый день!

Коллеги, прошу помочь начинающему программисту. Проблема вот в чем: при загрузке страницы браузер на секунду показывает контент без применения стилей и видимо еще без скриптов, при том, что все файлы в одной папке, а css и js внутри папки в этой папке. Как это устраняется? в чем может быть проблема? Благодарю за помощь!

Для примера адрес страницы [здесь](http://supersite.kz/maket/transit/index.html) (http://supersite.kz/maket/transit/index.html)

Comment: весь необходимый код разметка стили должны находиться непосредственно в вопросе, ссылки могут служить только дополнением

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько вариантов:

У вас добавляется класс `landing` в `body` при загрузке, можно на него стиль повесить:

```
body:not(.landing) > * { display: none }
```

Или перекрыть дивом весь контент и на `document ready` удалить его:

```
<div id="loading" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: white"></div>
```

Comment: Но ведь на большинстве сайтов такого не делается, а браузер их страницы без стилей всё равно не показывает

Comment: @andreymal, да, но тут я не очень понял что еще инджектится, такие баги бывают с клиентским `less` например. Подумал что тут та-же схема. Поэтому предложил такой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Это из-за подключения скриптов в `head` переместите подключение скриптов перед закрывающим тегом `body`. Похожий вопрос с хорошим ответом: [Где размещать css и js файлы - в начале или конце документа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561755/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-css-%D0%B8-js-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/561772#561772)

Answer (score 0):

@andreymal @Artem Gorlachev @greybutton все Ваши варианты перепробовал и не помогло, оказалась причина в том, что css файлы были обернуты в тэг `<nosript>` и его исключение исправило положение, почему так произошло ответа гугль не дал ответа(  @greybutton скрипты я все же перенес из хеда.   Всем спасибо.